# How to formally define this language of hereditarily finite sets?

Tags: set-theory, formal-languages

Suppose we have an alphabet of three characters, which are the left brace, the right brace, and the comma. I want to define a language over this alphabet which corresponds to the hereditarily finite sets. So, for example, the word $\{\}$ would be in the language, and it corresponds to the empty set. Also, the word $\{\{\},\{\}\}$ would be in the language, and it corresponds to the singleton containing the empty set. As you can see, I allow duplications of sets in my language. That is, every word in my language corresponds to a hereditarily finite set, but this correspondence is not injective. Also, the commas are essential in my language, so something like $\{\{\} \{\}\}$ would not be in my language. What is the formal definition of my intuitive notion of this language?

Comment: Just a thought: One does not strictly need the comma to define this language, as a comma is put precisely between } and {.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a *formal grammar* for your language simply as
$$S\to \{\}\ |\ \{L\}\\
L\to S\ |\ \{L,\,S\}$$
where $S$ represents your hereditary finite *lists* and $L$ represents the list contents.

Comment: I don't this language is regular (in the sense of formal language theory).

Comment: Ah yes, that might be true, indeed.